# How can I compute the power spectrum within a frequency band?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have discrete EEG signals and I'm trying to extract the absolute power from each channel. Sampling rate is 30Hz. The thing where I am confused is that I don't know how to program this accurately. 
Firstly I have done:

```
y = fft(eegdata);
```

This gives me a complex double. I have to compute this within a frequency band (alpha) + with a Hamming window + 50% overlap but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: My first attempt would be to take absolute magnitude of FFTied data and then after denormalizing, square the magnitude to get the power spectrum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Matlab's `pwelch` function. If your units are U (for example), then `pwelch` outputs U^2/(Hz s), so if you want the Power Spectral Density in U^2/Hz, multiply the result of pwelch by your sample interval (in your case, 1/30 seconds).

Default settings apply a Hamming window with 50% overlap.

Comment: Make sure to read Matlab's documentation on the function and also I found this paper which is very useful in helping understand Welch's method: https://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/5688766/